# Get Method Syntax to move Data Extension from SFMC via Postman

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, soap-api, dataextensions

I am new to API Calls, and Postman API Scripts.

I have a Data Extension in Sandbox SFMC, which i want to move to Postman via Postman API call.

I already have a script to get the access token from Sandbox SFMC.

GET call URL https://SUB-DOMAIN.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx

BODY:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <soapenv:Header>
<fueloauth>ZMgDiU9zs0vZXEr9XkNfjhMK</fueloauth>
<action>Retrieve</action>
  </soapenv:Header>
        <soapenv:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
      <RetrieveRequest>
         <ObjectType>DataExtensionObject[C6258E52-A99B-4BA3-8CF2- 
   2846ED90500A]</ObjectType>
         <Properties>Name</Properties>
         <Properties>FieldType</Properties>
         <Properties>IsPrimaryKey</Properties>
         <Properties>IsRequired</Properties>
         <Properties>MaxLength</Properties>
         <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
            <Property>CustomerKey</Property>
            <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
            <Value>C6258E52-A99B-4BA3-8CF2-2846ED90500A</Value>
         </Filter>
      </RetrieveRequest>
    </RetrieveRequestMsg>
```

[image]

Comment: can you add more detail on what you mean by 'move to Postman via Postman API call' do you mean you want to use an API call to retrieve it?

Comment: Hi Nat Fan, it might be worth reading [ask]

Comment: @Gortonington Thank you for responding. Yes, i meant to say how to use an API call to get the Data Extension.

Comment: @Robs Thanks for the pointer. I'm new to this, still learning.

Comment: Dont need to add auth in header on soap. To verify, you are using POST, right? And you are replacing `SUB-DOMAIN` with your sfmc sub domain, right? Also make sure that {{accessToken}} matches your var in the body

Comment: @NatFan - updated my answer, which hopefully will help straighten out the issues you were having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend checking the SFMC Documentation as they have a [sample](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_dataextension_object.htm) there. You would be required to use the SOAP API as the REST API does not currently have the capability to retrieve Data Extensions.

Below is a sample of the SOAP API Request: (*edited to target the actual data inside of the DE, instead of the info about the DE)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header>
      <fueloauth>{{accessToken}}</fueloauth>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
           <RetrieveRequest>
              <ObjectType>DataExtensionObject[myDEKey]</ObjectType>
              <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
              <Properties>Name</Properties>
              <Properties>Keys</Properties>
              <Properties>Type</Properties>
              <Properties>ModifiedDate</Properties>
              <Properties>CreatedDate</Properties>
           </RetrieveRequest>
        </RetrieveRequestMsg>
      </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

You would replace `{{accessToken}}` with your OAuth token and `myDEKey` with your DE's External Key.

The endpoint to do the POST request to would be gathered via the following for tenant specific endpoints:

> SOAP API with Your Tenant's Endpoints All instances:
>   https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx

or for legacy endpoints, you can go [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/wsdl-endpoint-links.htm) where it is dependent on the Instance you are using.

You would also want to make sure to include the following Header in your call:

`SoapAction: Retrieve`

---

Here are some screen shots that should hopefully help point you in the right direction(based on your feedback in the comments):

[image: Utilize POST action and input your SOAP Endpoint]

[image: Headers for your call]

[image: Body of the call]

and then you would replace:

- {{soapEndPoint}} with your tenant specific endpoint (should be able to find definitive version of it inside Admin in SFMC as well)
- {{accessToken}} with your POSTman variable for your OAuth token or replace it directly with your OAuth token
- myDEKey with the CustomerKey/ExternalKey of your Data Extension.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88378/discussion-on-answer-by-gortonington-get-method-syntax-to-move-data-extension-fr).